# How do I get a mean of exactly 0 when standardizing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale, mean

```
array = preprocessing.scale(array)
```

Im using the preprocessing module from sklearn in python, to change the mean of my array to 0. Problem is, I am getting really small numbers as my mean along the lines of 10^16, instead of 0.

Problem is that I truly need a mean of 0, else I cannot compute a covariance matrix for my signal.

How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the `decimal` module can help? I'm not sure if your problem is related to floating point error, but if it is, I'd look into that.

Comment: "10^16", you mean 10 ^-16!? Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error when computing the covariance matrix? I would suspect 10^-16 would be considered zero by the covariance calculation function...

Comment: What about using numpy.around? (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to make your mean zero to machine precision using `math.fsum`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.random((1000,))
>>> 
>>> a -= math.fsum(a)/a.size
# while fsum gives the exact solution rounded to machine precision
# there will be a residual error
# this must be borne by the smallest term
>>> a[np.argmin(np.abs(a))] -= math.fsum(a)
>>> 
# now we are zero to machine precision
>>> math.fsum(a)
0.0
```

The bad news is: numpy doesn't realize ....

```
>>> np.mean(a)
-3.552713678800501e-18
```